# Using facebook graph api explorer to post picture/link on feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-apps

I'm try to post to a feed using the facebook graph api explorer (I'm obtaining the token through that).

Usually, when you post a link manually in the feed, a summary is created. When I post a link through the graph explorer api app, it shows up as a regular link.

```
enter code here
  $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$_POST['group_id']."/feed";

  $postData = array(
    'access_token' => $_POST['token'], 
    'message' => $_POST['message'],
    'name' => 'name',
    'picture' => urlencode ('http://wildfireapp.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/img-payingfbcustomers1.png'),
    'link' => urlencode ('http://www.google.com'),     
    'scope'  => 'publish_stream');

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $graph_url,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
  ));
  $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
  curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Don’t `urlencode` URLs in this place – it _corrupts_ your data, because cURL will already handle everything that is necessary in this regard, and you are wrongfully adding another layer of URL encoding. And the `scope` parameter has nothing whatsoever to do in there – you use that while _requesting permissions_, not while _making a post_ (at that point you need to _have_ that permission already, otherwise it will fail).

Comment: Ok, thanks, but it still does not work. The scope parameter is ignored.

Comment: @CBroe can you please check this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157808/how-to-post-photo-to-facebook-page-feed-not-posted-by-others